# If $N(T) = \{0\}$ and $R(T)$ is closed then exists $C > 0$ such that $ \parallel T(x) \parallel \geq C\parallel x \parallel$, for all $x \in E$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ two Banach spaces and $T \in L(E; F)$. If $N(T) = \{0\}$ and $R(T)$ is closed then exists $C > 0$ such that $ \parallel T(x) \parallel \geq C \parallel x \parallel$, for all $x \in E$.

Here $R(T) = \{Tx; x \in E\}$ is the range of $T$ and $N(T) = \{ x \in E; Tx = 0\}$ is the kernel of $T$.

*Comments:* I'm trying to use Hahn-Banach Theorem, 
but I do not know if this is the way.

Comment: Have you tried the open mapping theorem?

Comment: Do you perchance mean $\Vert T(x) \Vert \ge C\Vert x \Vert$?  As written, $C$ doesn't really enter in, does it? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $R(T)$ is closed, and $T$ injective, $T:E\rightarrow R(T)$ is bijective, thus invertible from open mappin theorem. Let $U$ its inverse, $\|x\|=\|U(T(x))\|\leq \|U\|\|T(x)\|$. This implies that $\|T(x)\|\geq {1\over{\|U\|}}\|x\|$, take $C={1\over{\|U\|}}$.